# How to close the pop up window when I click outside of popup window

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is `XAML` code for open popup window IsChecked *btnViewDetail*, I need to close popup on click out side of popup window.

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnViewDetail}" PopupAnimation="Fade" Width="300" Height="225" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=svTotalStock}" Placement="Top" StaysOpen="False">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Raw Materials details" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
                   Padding="7,6,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" 
                   Margin="0,2,59,0"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Name="btnViewDetail" Header="View Details"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I wonder why `StaysOpen = "False"` does not work?

Comment: StaysOpen = "False" working when focus out user control.

Answer (score 30):

property of Popup `StaysOpen = false` do this work.

Answer (score 6):

if `StaysOpen` property cannot handle your situation, you have to capture `MouseDown` event on your Window when your container element(in your situation, `Grid`) has `Focusable="True"`

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    gridContainer.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two properties you have to assign:

`StaysOpen = false` ,

When the StaysOpen property is set to true, Popup stays open until it is explicitly closed by setting the IsOpen property to false. When StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside the Popup control.

Next, set popup's child : `Focusable = false`

Then in other User Control which u wants tp open the popup, define an EventTrigger on `UIElement.LostMouseCapture` to set the popup's `IsOpen = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the control from where the popup is opened. I even had same issue and reloved by opening the popup by MouseLeftButtonUp of the target.

Answer (score 0):

add a togglebutton and bind IsOpen property of popup to IsChecked property of ToggleButton as shown below:

```
    <ToggleButton IsChecked = {Binding ElementName = "Your_Popup_Name", Path = "IsOpen", Mode = "TwoWay"} Opacity = "0" , Panel.ZIndex = "1">
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem?